# chrome 3d transform rendering-issue?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, google-chrome

I am currently building a 3D Carousel in HTML/CSS(LESS)/jQuery ([following this guide](https://www.sitepoint.com/building-3d-rotating-carousel-css-javascript/))

Here is a live example too: [demo](http://shop.rekkt.de/)

GIF Opera initial State: https://i.gyazo.com/c3482f070ecfa7abe119bc8e643394e3.gif
GIF Chrome initial State: https://i.gyazo.com/e0877b6d03336fa5edf533dd50305890.gif

Chrome does not render the elements before and after the starting-element (on initial page load). After pressing the Next or Prev Button the elements suddenly appear.
Changing the transform: rotateY() (on elements class: "carousel-item") just for a little bit back and forth the elements suddenly render.
The now appearing elements instantly disappear once you change the window size of the chrome browser.

I can't replicate the issue in Opera, which is also a Webkit-based browser.
I am running Chrome on Version: 62.0.3202.75 official build 32 bit

**EDIT:** I just realized that Version 62 is pretty old, so I updated to V67 and the problem seems to be fixed by now. Does anyone know at what point they fixed that, or if there is even a fix for older versions?